# Cannot connect Django to SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc

this is my first thread here so forgive me if something is wrong.

I'm creating a CRM sorta application in Django and trying to connect to a MSSQL database using pyodbc. I manage to connect and Django even created some tables dbo.django_migrations and dbo.django_content_type (which is blank). But when I run I get a lot of errors:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 146, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 69, in dispatch
    if request.user.is_authenticated and app_settings.AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS:
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 246, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 382, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 11, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 177, in get_user
    user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 60, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 238, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 43, in load
    s = self._get_session_from_db()
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 32, in _get_session_from_db
    return self.model.objects.get(
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1169, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\Users\thardt\Documents\Web-Development\employeeweb\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 553, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
[13/Apr/2021 16:36:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 203174
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong. I've read countless threads with similar problems but nothing seems to help.

My settings.py:

```html
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Employee_Database_Test',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx', 
        'HOST': 'ss-sql-02',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    # }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should run makemigrations and migrate before running the sever.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah. I did run the migrations but I always get a ton of errors. But if I run migrate --fake everything seems fine. And if I go and apply the migrations again I get 
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'name', table 'Employee_Database_Test.dbo.django_content_type'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of head-scratching... I've downgraded Django from 3.2 to 3.0 and Allauth to 0.42.0. Run all the migrations and magically everything worked. I'm not sure what's the cause of the problem, to be honest, probably just some incompatibility between Django 3.2 or Allauth and pyobdc maybe?